# C scanning for files, . and .. appear

Tags: c, file-io, dirent.h

I have the function:

```
char *readFile(char *dir){
    DIR *dirPointer;
    int file_count = 0;
    struct dirent *file;
    if ((dirPointer = opendir(dir)) == NULL){
        printf("Directory not found, try again\n");
        return NULL;
    }else{
        printf("Reading files in directory\n");
        while((file = readdir(dirPointer)) != NULL){
            file_count++;
            printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", file_count);
    closedir(dirPointer);
    return dir;
}
```

For a folder with the following files: hi, hello.rar, aaa.txt, asdq.txt, xzca.txt, it prints that there were 7 files found, including two random files named "." and "..". Why is it including these two extra 'files'? I have invisible files turned on, there are only the 5 files I listed in the directory.

Comment: `.` and `..` in POSIX are the directory itself and the parent directory, respectively. You can see that they are directories by `stat()`ing them.

Comment: try typing `ls -l -a` in your terminal...

Comment: `opendir` can fail for reasons other than non-existence.  Try `if((dirPointer=opendir(dir)) == NULL ) { perror(dir); return NULL; }`

Comment: The names `.` and `..` are anything but 'random'; they are present in every directory, and they are names of directories.  They are a key part of how the hierarchical file system works.